# Twitter TON API - cULR vs twurl 400 error (csv upload)

Tags: csv, curl, twitter

Not getting a lot of traction on the twitter developer community, so I thought I'd post here as well.

twurl/ton-upload:

```
<- "POST https://ton.twitter.com/1.1/ton/bucket/ta_partner HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
Accept: /
User-Agent: OAuth gem v0.4.7
Content-Type: text/comma-separated-values
Content-Length: 12261
X-Ton-Expires: Sun, 20 Mar 2016 16:12:39 GMT
Authorization: OAuth oauth_body_hash=\"REDACTED\", oauth_consumer_key=\"REDACTED\", oauth_nonce=\"REDACTED\", oauth_signature=\"REDACTED\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"REDACTED\", oauth_token=\"REDACTED\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"
Connection: close
Host: ton.twitter.com
```

curl:

```
POST /1.1/ton/bucket/ta_partner HTTP/1.1
Host: ton.twitter.com
Accept: /
Content-Length: 12261
X-TON-Expires: Tue, 15 Mar 2016 16:12:30 GMT
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="REDACTED", oauth_nonce="REDACTED", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="REDACTED", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_token="REDACTED", oauth_signature="REDACTED%3D"
Content-Type: text/comma-separated-values; boundary=------------------------25aceae34d75d12f
```

cURL response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< cache-control: no-cache
< content-length: 0
< date: Thu, 10 Mar 2016 16:12:23 GMT
< server: tsa_a
< set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A145762634383261612; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 10-Mar-2018 16:12:23 UTC
< strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519
< x-connection-hash: d6ebefd610faece8fe17da88738cac1f
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-rate-limit-limit: 50
< x-rate-limit-remaining: 48
< x-rate-limit-reset: 1457627079
< x-response-time: 13
< x-tsa-request-body-time: 74
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
```

First difference I can see is oauth_body_hash, but I can't seem to find any twitter documentation as to what I'm supposed to put there. There's also the "boundary" added by curl.

Any thoughts as to what I'm missing here?

Comment: Please elaborate some more on expected results and possible errors. This question, as it stands, looks like "Here is my junk, you figure out what's wrong with it", which may be why the Twitter community responds so poorly too.

Comment: Expected results would be "not a 400 error".  I've followed their documentation, but for example in https://dev.twitter.com/rest/ton/single-chunk the example lacks the oauth_body_hash.  I figure whatever is wrong should leap out at anyone who has a working ton / cURL script.  And normally if there was some sort of error past 400 (error, xyz parameter missing or something), I'd use that as a jumping off point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I've found the solution.

The problem is boundary=------------------------25aceae34d75d12f after all.

Twitter does not accept "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" (per https://dev.twitter.com/rest/ton).

I was using

```
$postdata = array(
            'file_contents' => '@'.$payload
        );
```

along with setting header:

```
'Content-Type: ' . $content_type
```

Unfortunately, this appears to just patch over the fact that php considers it to be x-www-form-urlencoded.

So, my solution was to change payload to:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents($payload);
```

Once this was done, requests shifted to 201's.

God I hope this helps someone else - this was surprisingly annoying to solve.

Comment: Yeah, the example given in the docs won't even run correctly.

Comment: That's been my experience with the documentation.  I hope by putting this out here other people will have an easier google search for the answer!

Comment: Probably worth posting a link to your answer back to https://twittercommunity.com/ if you haven't already.  There might be clarifications to the documentation they can make.